# Gitlab webhook payload - detect Service Desk

Tags: gitlab

I'm starting to use Gitlab and I have some automation pieces I need to build out using webhooks.
These automations are only for issues that come into the Service Desk area.

When I look at the JSON payload Confidential Issues and Confidential Comments, which element(s) indicate if this relates to a Service Desk issue/comment?

A non-Service Desk issue can also be marked as Confidential, so that doesn't seem to be the correct way to identify the activity as being related to a Service Desk issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for some piece of information that a new issue has been created in Service Desk, then you can look for the `GitLab Support Bot` as the author, basically:

```
"author":{
  "id":1257257, ## double check if the ID number is the same for your instance
  "name":"GitLab Support Bot",
  "username":"support-bot",
  "state":"active",
  "avatar_url":"https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/f21cf9717c13c6f591e183c2b2484d9a?s=80\u0026d=identicon",
  "web_url":"https://gitlab.example.com/support-bot"}
```

All external comments (replies the Service Desk gets via email) will also show up as the `support-bot` user.